# Android: sharing the Facebook page post

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-share

I'm creating an Android app and I need to integrate some Facebook functions in this app.

Among them I need to share some Facebook page posts. I try to use native share button.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

But I can't achieve the sharing of the page post. When I try to share the page post I can only share the page.

For example, I try to share this post 
https://www.facebook.com/ArsenalThePrideofEngland/posts/863092823730119

and as a result I get the sharing of this page

https://www.facebook.com/ArsenalThePrideofEngland

I read the Graph API docs about the sharing and I discover that it's not possible to use it for sharing.

Is it possible at all to share the Facebook page post using custom Android app?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using? Do you provide the permalink to the post in the 'link' field of the Share action?